# Setting up a view to list the current user's activity details

Tags: drupal-views

bit of help appreciated please!

I'd like to create a view that shows authenticated users the details of some specific activities that've been added to their record (added by a different user, the target is the 'with contact').

**Fields to be shown**

> Activity type
>
> Activity description

**Filter type**

> Activity type

Where I'm falling down is setting the relationship or context to limit the results only to the currently logged-in user. I've had a look through Stackexchange but couldn't find what I'm looking for - would anyone be able to assist?

Comment: Hey Graham - how did you get on?

Answer (score 3):

have a look at [this one](https://www.fuzion.co.nz/blogs/view-show-current-users-activities). Not sure it has the Source v Target how you want it but it should provide an example of how to ensure the logged in User sees 'their' Activities. Good luck

In summary.

- Create an Activities based View
- Set the Relationship up in Views to join the relevant type of Contact to the Activity
- Add another relationship to join that Contact to their drupal user.
- Add a filter that sets 'current user IS Active) (or similar drupal description of the filter) and that Filter will use the Relationship you created above and mean it checks 'who is logged in' and then server up the Activities they are the Target of (or whatever Activity Contact type you need)